# Can't use formdata sent value to controller

Tags: javascript, ajax, codeigniter

I have problem: I can't use Formdata sent value to controller. I want to see value from Formdata after I sent value to controller and I try to sent from data to controller but I don't understand why controller return all code HTML.

**THIS HTML CODE**

```
<body>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div>
            <form id="submitForm" method="post">
                <input type="text" name="amount" value="100">
                <input type="submit" value="submit">
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#submitForm').submit(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            var formData = new FormData(this);
            console.log(formData);

            $.ajax({
                type:'POST',
                url:'<?php base_url("Notifyoffense/test") ?>',
                data: formData,
                cache: false,
                contentType: false,
                processData: false,
                // dataType: 'JSON',
                success:function(data){
                    alert (data)
                }
            })
        });
    });
</script>
```

**THIS CONTROLLER**

```
public function test()
{
    print_r($this->input->post());
    die;
}
```

**OUTPUT**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/isKdF.jpg)

Comment: We can help you better if you include the content of your image as formatted plain text in your question.

Comment: Inspite of alerting the response, You should log it in to the console. That will give you meaningful result.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to `echo` your action url

```
$.ajax({
    type:'POST',
    url:'<?php echo base_url("Notifyoffense/test") ?>',
    data: formData,
    cache: false,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    dataType: 'JSON',
    success:function(data){
    alert (data)
}
```